# React and Firebase: Show Components only after successful login

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I am trying to make an app for my billiards league using React and Firebase. I want to have users log in and THEN be able to see the full app (calculator for determining races, schedules, teams, etc.). I am storing the status of whether someone is logged in or not in the parent component's state (e.g.: `this.state = { loggedIn: true }`). The Firebase login/logout works just fine, as does the React conditional rendering of components based off the aforementioned state. The state defaults as `false` and changes to true based on `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` (which also functions just fine).

The problem I'm having is that there's currently nothing stopping an enterprising individual - one who has no account with my app and is not logged in - from opening the React dev tools and toggling `loggedIn` to `true`, and thus revealing all the goodies.

I've viewed a number of tutorials (like this [CC-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/firebase-react-part-2-user-authentication/) one) for React and Firebase that say to do exactly that - store the authentication status in the component state. I also think there is an easy way to do what I need my app to do, but I probably am just overthinking/ too noob. Any pointers?

Comment: better not to use one page for all - make one page for login and other for all other staff

Comment: You will validate the data of the request in the server anyway. I don't think you should really worry about client data. It can be manipulated. It is accessible too. So you don't really reveal anything. It is already there for someone who knows how to change the component state.

Comment: Thanks Ali. But, I *do* need to worry about it: Right now, if you  (as in, you, Ali Ankarali, or anyone else on the internet at this very moment...) don't have an account, you can open the dev tools, toggle loggedIn to true, and see all the stuff that I want to be inaccessible... I want that to NOT happen. Is there some concept I'm not understanding/missing?